# Text area with 12 px more in firefox compare to other browser

Tags: html, css, textarea

this problem occur in wordpress  contact form 7

[image]

help to clear the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add class

> textarea {
>       overflow: auto;
>       resize: none;
>       width: 150px; 
>       height:100px; }